# Why $\|f-g\|=0$ if and only if $f=g$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm learning Fourier Transformation lately, and in the [Course Reader](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoftaee261/book-fall-07.pdf) page 23, it defines
$\|f\|=\left(\int_0^1 \left|f(t)\right|^2 dt\right)^{1/2}$.

And then $\|f-g\|=0$ if and only if $f=g$.

My question is what does it mean exactly by $f=g$? Is it a new definition of $f=g$?
Since, for example $f=0$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x=0.5$ and $0$ otherwise, will result $f=g$.

Comment: The correct statement is $f=g$ [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere). Changing the value of a function at  single point does not change the value of the integral so unless we are able to rule this out (by e.g. requiring $f,g$ to both be continuous everywhere) then $f,g$ can differ on a countable set.

Comment: Thanks @Winther. But by saying almost everywhere, do we need specify the measure before the definition of this norm?

Comment: In general yes.